# pandas/matplotlib add labels above bar charts w/multiple column groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am brand new to Pandas and matplotlib, and I want to add labels to show the numbers associated with each column in the bar chart. I found solutions when there is a single bar char associated with x axis label, but I have multiple.

Here is my code:

```
df.set_index("HbA1c",drop=True,inplace=True)
df.plot.bar()
plt.yscale("log")
plt.show()
```

[My bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLx61.png)

df is a data frame that looks like this:

[data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixyT9.png)

Comment: The official reference would be helpful.[this page](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py)